# How to order WordPress Rest API data

Tags: rest-api, order, json

I am pulling in some data via the Rest API:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/speaker?include[]=3116&include[]=3249&include[]=3170&include[]=3416&include[]=3181&include[]=1857&include[]=3563
```

The data loads fine, but the order is out of whack.

I was expecting the first result to be ID '3116' as that's the first included id in my URL.

How do I pull in data orderd by the URL id?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `orderby=include` to your GET request.

See the docs here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments

Comment: I think, it should actually read `orderby=include`

Comment: Thanks @CWBudde